# Issue with redirect in ModelAndView in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a simple index page and controller. I just want my controller to redirect to the index page if the credentials of user doesn't match. I'm using ModelAndView as my return type in the controller.

Here's my code for the controller:

```
public class LoginController {  

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView loginResult(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res,RedirectAttributes redir,Model model) {
InfoEmployee inf = new InfoEmployee();
        InfoManager inf2 = new InfoManager();
        String uname=req.getParameter("username");  
        //Putting the username in the session object


        String pwd=req.getParameter("pwd");  
        String dept = req.getParameter("dept");
        String name1 = inf.getName();
        String message1 = "Welcome "+name1;  
        String name2 = inf2.getName();
        String message2 = "Welcome "+name2;
        model.addAttribute("message", "sorry message");
        if(uname.equals(inf.getUsername())&&pwd.equals(inf.getPassword())&&dept.equals(inf.getDept()))
        {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("uname",inf.getName());
            return new ModelAndView("employeeLoginResult", "message", message1); 

        }
        else if(uname.equals(inf2.getUsername())&&pwd.equals(inf2.getPassword())&&dept.equals(inf2.getDept()))
        {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("uname",inf2.getName());
            return new ModelAndView("adminLoginResult", "message", message2); 
        }
        else
        {

            //ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            //modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/index.jsp");
            //redir.addFlashAttribute("message","Sorry");
            //return modelAndView;
            //redir.addFlashAttribute(message1, "Sorry");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.jsp","message","Sorry username password error");

            //return new ModelAndView("Redirect:/index","message","Sorry, user name or password error");
            //return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("index.jsp"),"message","Sorry, user name or password error");
            //return new ModelAndView("RedirectToIndex", "message","Sorry, user name or password error"); 
        }
    }
```

I have tried using flash attribute but the URL still gets append with attributes passed.
And here's my index page:

```
<b><span class="heading">LOGIN USER</span></b>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="login.html" method="Post">
            <div class="form_style">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"/>
            <select name="dept">
                <option>IT</option>
                <option>Admin</option>
                <option>HR</option>
                <option>Marketing</option>
            </select>
            <input type="Submit" value="submit">
            <%
                String message=request.getParameter("message"); 
            %>
            <%=message %>
            <span>${message}</span>
            <span>${message1}</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I just can't seem to print the message I have sent through redirect with ${message} in my index page. Every method appends the URL with the message. I want to know if the issue can be resolved while using some different method or If anyone can tell me the use of RedirectAttributes as when I used it, it still added attributes to the URL.

Simply put, I just want to show that username or password that the user has entered is wrong in my index page. If i can go to my index page without the help of redirect then that suggestion is also appreciated.

Any suggestion or help as appreciated. Thank you for the same.

**EDIT:**

**Here's my dispatcher servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<!--    <mvc:annotation-driven ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true" /> -->
<!--<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config> -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"></context:component-scan> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/> 
<!--      <mvc:resources location="webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/stylesheets/main.css" mapping="/stylesheets/**"></mvc:resources>  -->
</beans>
```

The directory::

[image]

Comment: Share your `application.properties` as well

Comment: I have added my dispatcher class in the edits

Comment: Also, your directory strucuture

Comment: I added the directory as well.

Comment: Can you try moving `index.jsp` inside the jsp folder and then create an object of the `ModelAndView`like you did for a success scenario?

Comment: The suggestion you are implying will give me the desired result and I wouldn't have to pass the redirect mapping in the ModelAndView in the else statement rather just index will work. But the problem with this is that I want my index outside my WEB_INF not inside it. And I wanna ask whether putting my index in my jsp folder will result in any other discrepancies??

Comment: *I want my index outside my WEB_INF not inside it* - Why?

Comment: Will me moving the index page into my WEB-INF result in any dependencies? I just wanted to know that as I have no idea what will be my project behaviour after that.

Comment: It shouldn't, ideally we should group all .jsp's in  one folder.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I'll move my index to the jsp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `index.jsp` inside the jsp folder and then create an object of the ModelAndView like you did for a success scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried by myself but flashattributes can be accessed from flashmap stored in current session. Please try that as well and see if something gets appended.

link: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes

Comment: How does this answer the question?